# Antlr V4 grammar for XQuery 3.1

Tags: xquery, antlr4

I found the following Antlr 4 grammar:

https://gist.github.com/JoeyAcc/829c28fcf18091ed6ebfcf91d7519f58

I received the following error while trying to generate the code from it:

```
error(134): xquery31.g4:178:26: rule reference PragmaContentsInternal is not currently supported in a set
error(134): xquery31.g4:264:25: rule reference DirPIContentsInternal is not currently supported in a set
error(134): xquery31.g4:268:32: rule reference CDataSectionContentsInternal is not currently supported in a set
error(134): xquery31.g4:311:17: rule reference StringConstructorCharsInternal is not currently supported in a set
warning(156): xquery31.g4:377:59: invalid escape sequence
warning(156): xquery31.g4:378:60: invalid escape sequence
warning(156): xquery31.g4:392:30: invalid escape sequence
warning(156): xquery31.g4:394:30: invalid escape sequence
error(134): xquery31.g4:416:27: rule reference CommentContentsInternal is not currently supported in a set
warning(146): xquery31.g4:13:0: non-fragment lexer rule Prolog can match the empty string
warning(146): xquery31.g4:110:0: non-fragment lexer rule WindowVars can match the empty string
warning(146): xquery31.g4:127:0: non-fragment lexer rule OrderModifier can match the empty string
warning(146): xquery31.g4:211:0: non-fragment lexer rule PredicateList can match the empty string
warning(146): xquery31.g4:248:0: non-fragment lexer rule DirAttributeList can match the empty string
warning(146): xquery31.g4:261:0: non-fragment lexer rule DirCommentContents can match the empty string
error(99): xquery31.g4::: grammar xquery31 has no rules
```

Are there any suggestions to fix this ANTLR V4 grammar?

The [EBNF for XQuery v3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#nt-bnf) is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own Antlr4 grammar for XQuery 3.1.  It is at: https://github.com/xqdoc/xqdoc/tree/master/src/main/antlr4/org/xqdoc

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your error message is very telling.  And if you look at the grammar, every word is capitalized.  That means that this is just the lexer rules, and ones with errors at that.  The parser rules are entirely absent.  Perhaps contact the poster of this grammar or search for the parser rules before investing time in this file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the conclusion of the work by JoeyACC is here - https://gist.github.com/JoeyAcc/375663dfc21cd7ec4d35ea8f7ff251d0#file-xquery31-g4

Another approach would be to take this Antlrv4 XQuery 1.0 grammar and add the missing parts for 3.1: https://github.com/bluezio/xquery-parser